# Build Docker image from manifest

Tags: image, docker, manifest, azure-container-service, amazon-ecr

Not looking for questions about how I got into this position just looking for help with the issue.

I received a Docker manifest via a `tar.gz` file. Once unzipped I see what I now know is a Docker Manifest.

[image]

What is the simplest was for me to turn this manifest into an image that will show up when I run `docker images`? Then I can tag and push to my private container repository.

Comment: Usually you can [`docker load`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) it, if it was produced by `docker save`; I'm not sure how you'd get that format otherwise.  Is there relevant application code that's producing or consuming this file format?

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I actually ran the command against the compressed file like this. `docker load < <file name>.tar.gz` it took a moment because the image was large but in successfully loaded it in a way where it was in the `docker images` list.